# WPF - Close RadPane Programatically using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I want to close RadPane programatically. How can I get hold of current RadPane and how to trigger close event ?

```
 <telerik:RadButton Content="Close" x:Name="button4" Command="{Binding ClosePaneCommand}" />   

 public ICommand ClosePaneCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(ClosePaneExecute);
        }
    }
```

I did some research and come up with the below code.

```
 RadPaneGroup container = App.Current.MainWindow.FindName(ContentContainerName) as RadPaneGroup;

        foreach (RadPane pane in container.Items)
        {
            if (pane.Content.GetType() == typeof(ScrollViewer))
            {
                ScrollViewer scrollViewer = pane.Content as ScrollViewer;
                if (scrollViewer.Content.GetType().BaseType == typeof(UserControl))
                {
                    UserControl control = scrollViewer.Content as UserControl;
                    ContentViewModel contentViewModel = control.DataContext as ContentViewModel;
                    //Here is my Question
                    if (contentViewModel == viewModel)
                    {
                        pane.RemoveFromParent();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can we compare these two ViewModels and how to get the current ViewModel ?

```
 if (contentViewModel == viewModel)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, We can remove like this.

```
 RadPaneGroup container = App.Current.MainWindow.FindName(ContentContainerName) as RadPaneGroup;

foreach (RadPane pane in container.Items)
 {
  if (pane.IsActive)
  {
    pane.RemoveFromParent();
    break;
  }
 }
```